# EDIT : input and output files on C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So, for some reason when I'm reading from a certain text file, I'm only reading and outputting the first and third one. I'm not sure why it's not reading it at all, regardless if there is a negative number or not for the 2nd guy. Here is the text file i'm using:

EDIT: Fixed the problem of the reading, but now I want to make it realize that if it reads an empty file, it recognizes that it is empty, do not terminate but give a message like "file was empty".

Joseph Kradin III

5000 6 4

Joe Boo

15000 2 12

Nancy Adams

15000 2 12

here is a part of my code where my loop and fin stuff is all there:

```
fin >> firstName;
        getline(fin, lastName);
        fin >> deposit >> year >> numCompound;

    do
    {

        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

        // if statements to determine the interest rate depending on the years

        if (year >= 5)
            rate = 0.045;
        else if ((year < 5) & (year >= 4))
            rate = 0.04;
        else if ((year < 4) & (year >= 3))
            rate = 0.035;
        else if ((year < 3) & (year >= 2))
            rate = 0.025;
        else if ((year < 2) & (year >= 1))
            rate = 0.02;
        else
            rate = 0.015;

        if (deposit < 0 || year < 0 || numCompound < 0)
        {
            cout << fullName << " You have entered a negative number" << endl;
            fout << fullName << " You have entered a negative number" << endl;

        }

        else if (deposit > 0 || year > 0 || numCompound > 0)
        {
            numname++;

            // finding the value for amount of money aquired after n years, including interest.
            moneyAquired = deposit * pow((1 + rate / numCompound), numCompound*year);

            // finding earned interest

            earnedInterest = moneyAquired - deposit;

            // For the Total Deposit entered

            totaldeposit += deposit;

            // For total earned interest

            totalinterest += earnedInterest;

            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << setw(20) << left << fullName << setw(15) << year << setw(14) << rate * 100 << "$" << setw(15) << deposit << "$" << setw(15) << earnedInterest << "$" << setw(20) << moneyAquired << endl;

            fout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << setw(20) << left << fullName << setw(15) << year << setw(14) << rate * 100 << "$" << setw(15) << deposit << "$" << setw(15) << earnedInterest << "$" << setw(20) << moneyAquired << endl;

        }

    } while (fin >> firstName >> lastName >> deposit >> year >> numCompound && !fin.eof());

    //end of do while loop
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Yes, here is everything you could think of posting, except an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
while (fin >> firstName >> lastName >> deposit >> year >> numCompound && !fin.eof())
```

to the beginning instead of **do** and remove

```
fin >> firstName;
getline(fin, lastName);
fin >> deposit >> year >> numCompound;
```

Comment: Yeah I actually did exactly that without looking at your reply haha. But uhh I have another problem. Idk how to make the program realize that the file is empty? Professor in the direction says that we shouldn't terminate when reading empty file but give a message like "the file was empty".

Comment: Well add a counter and if ends not increased, print **file was empty**.
Also don't duplicate code: a good reason to replace `do {...} while(...);` with simply `while{...}`